# Locally free sheaf generated by global sections and vanishing cohomology on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-cohomology

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf on $C$ satisfying $H^1(\mathcal{F})=0$. Is it then true that $\mathcal{F}$ is generated by global sections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: What about $C=\mathbb{P}^1$, and $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}(-1)$?

Comment: @Youcis: Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If we have $H^1(\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal O(-1))=0$, then $\mathcal F$ is globally generated due to Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity.

Comment: I don't think you actually said anything. Is your claim that $\text{reg}(\mathcal{F})\leqslant -1$ for all $\mathcal{F}$? CM regularity is a number, not a theorem as you're stating it. Am I being silly?

Comment: If we have $H^1(\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal O(-1))=0$, we deduce that $\mathcal F$ is $0$-regular with respect to $\mathcal O(1)$ (We are on a curve), hence globally generated.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I was forgetting that we're on a curve! Thanks!